# I got this error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, dataset, frames

**Python**

Iam trying to extract frames from UCF-101 dataset, but I got this error:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).
Iam using Anaconda 1.7.2

This line shows the argument error: sequence_type, sequence_name = video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("/")[-2:]

```
import av
import glob
import os
import time
import tqdm
import datetime
import argparse


def extract_frames(video_path):
    frames = []
    video = av.open(video_path)
    for frame in video.decode(0):
        yield frame.to_image()


prev_time = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--dataset_path", type=str, default="UCF-101", help="Path to UCF-101 dataset")
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    print(opt)

    time_left = 0
    video_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(opt.dataset_path, "*", "*.avi"))
    for i, video_path in enumerate(video_paths):
        sequence_type, sequence_name = video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("/")[-2:]
        sequence_path = os.path.join(f"{opt.dataset_path}-frames", sequence_type, sequence_name)

        if os.path.exists(sequence_path):
            continue

        os.makedirs(sequence_path, exist_ok=True)

        # Extract frames
        for j, frame in enumerate(
            tqdm.tqdm(
                extract_frames(video_path, time_left),
                desc=f"[{i}/{len(video_paths)}] {sequence_name} : ETA {time_left}",
            )
        ):
            frame.save(os.path.join(sequence_path, f"{j}.jpg"))

        # Determine approximate time left
        videos_left = len(video_paths) - (i + 1)
        time_left = datetime.timedelta(seconds=videos_left * (time.time() - prev_time))
        prev_time = time.time()
```

Comment: Print `video_path` just before the error then we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Print out `video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("/")[-2:]` before trying to assign it to a 2-tuple and you will see why you are getting the error Not enough values to unpack.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It displays all paths which inlcudes in the dataset folder

Comment: @BoarGules It displays the path of video without the .avi extension

Comment: This part `.split("/")[-2:]` returns up to two strings; note "up to". Since you have not shown what the value of `video_path` is at the point of error, I can only point out that the `[-2:]` slicing is giving you a list consisting of just one string and not two as you were expecting. Perhaps `video_path` does not contain forward slashes.

Comment: I suggested you print the value of `video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("/")[-2:]`. Since it contains a call to `split("\")` it can't be a string representing a path, it will be a list of strings. I still think you should try it.

Answer (score 1):

Your responses to advice and questions in the comments suggest to me that this code is not really yours and you have no clear idea what this line

```
sequence_type, sequence_name = video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("/")[-2:]
```

is supposed to do. So let me explain. It takes `video_path`, which is a full path to an `.avi` file, for example `'~/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/myfile.avi'`. It splits off the extension `.avi`, and from what remains, that is, `'~/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/myfile'`, it takes *the last two elements*, that is `subsubfolder` and `myfile`, and uses those as values for `sequence_type` and `sequence_name`.

But for that to work, `video_path` has to contain both `subsubfolder` and `myfile`, with a slash between, so, at a minimum, `'subsubfolder/myfile.avi'`.

One of the pathnames returned by `glob.glob()` does not contain even one `/` character. That is why `split("/")` is returning a 1-list, which is not enough to unpack into the 2-tuple  `(sequence_type, sequence_name)`, resulting in the error *Not enough values to unpack*.

The only reason that occurs to me why this might be happening is that you are working on Windows where the path separator is \ not /. That would mean that the pathname your code is getting back from `glob.glob()` would be something like    `'C:\Users\folder\subfolder\subsubfolder\myfile.avi'`. No slashes: there couldn't be, because Windows filenames can't contain slashes.

That is the reason why commenters asked you to show us *the value you were trying to unpack*, instead of just telling us about it. Programming problems are very often about tiny specific details. So, in the absence of an explicit response from you, this is still only a guess, but if the guess is correct, the line that is giving you the error should be

```
sequence_type, sequence_name = video_path.split(".avi")[0].split("\\")[-2:]
```

(note, you have to double the backslash) or, if you want to the code to be platform-independent,

```
sequence_type, sequence_name = video_path.split(".avi")[0].split(os.path.sep)[-2:]
```

Comment: +1 for the well explained and platform independent solution. I will surely keep it in mind for any future implementation